# How to get inputId in React Select?

Tags: reactjs

Below is my React Select code snippet. How do I get this inputId in the onChange function?

```
<Select
   value={{ label: selected, value: selected }}
   onChange={onChange}
   options={options}
   inputId={id}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const onChange = (event) => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    // [...]
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow function like this:

```
onChange={(e) => onChange(e, id)}
```

and declare function `onChange`

```
const onChange = (e, id) => {//do something with e and id}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using normal select

```
 const onChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    // some codes
  };
```

if you are using `react-select`, it returns value `object`

```
{ label: 'Select 3', value: 'select 3' }
```

- example

  ```
  const onChange = val => {
    // val = { label: 'Select 3', value: 'select 3' }
    setValue(val);
  };
  ```

Sample Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4zfnkq